# How to add space before and after paragraph?

Tags: spacing, paragraphs

I have text in this structure (simplified):

```
\paragraph{\textbf{\uv{Main question is.... ?}}}

Main question is divided into three subquestions....    

\paragraph{Sub question 1.} Sub question 1.....
\paragraph{Sub question 2.} Sub question 2.....
\paragraph{Sub question 3.} Sub question 3.....
```

but paragraph "Main question is divided into three..." is placed immediately after previous paragraph but I would like to place some space before and after this paragraph. For some reason (for me unknown) tag `\vspace` doesn't work.

How can I create space between these paragraphs?

Comment: `\paragraph`  is a section heading so shouldn't the last three be `\subparagraph` it seems odd that you have them at the same section level?

Comment: `\setlength\parskip{2cm}` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\bigskip` with a blank line before like this:

```
\paragraph{\textbf{\uv{Main question is.... ?}}}

\bigskip
Main question is divided into three subquestions....
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question wasn't so clear as the fragments were too small to show the desired layout, in particular `\paragraph{..}` is an inline heading for the following paragraph text but you did not show any following text.  The following document uses `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph` with non zero `\parskip` which is possibly closer to what you want, although the exact spacing could be tuned.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{Main question} Main question ..

Main question is divided into three subquestions....    

\subparagraph{Sub question1} Sub question 1.....
\subparagraph{Sub question} Sub question 2.....
\subparagraph{Sub question} Sub question 3.....

\end{document}
```