# Fill vertical space before paragraph

Tags: fill, vspace

I'm working with small pages and I'll have one, two, or three short paragraphs per page.

I would like these paragraphs to be vertically centered and approximately-evenly spaced.

I am close with `\setlength{\parskip}{\fill}`  and defining a `\page` command which is `\vspace{\fill}\newpage` or `\vfill\newpage`.  However, I'm having trouble getting that equal amount of space before the first paragraph of each page.

Here's MWE demonstrating the issue

[image]

`\vspace{\fill}`/`\vfill` is discarded after a page-break, and so does nothing before the first paragraph, but `\vspace*{\fill}` creates a space that is much larger than what `\parskip` or `\vspace{\fill}` later on the page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=88mm, paperwidth=62mm, margin=4mm, nomarginpar, showframe]{geometry}

\setlength{\parskip}{\fill}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newcommand{\page}{\vspace{\fill}\newpage\vspace{\fill}}

\begin{document}

\page

This should be at approximately 50\%.

\page

This should be at approx 33\%.

This should be at approx 66\%.

\page

This should be at approx 25\%.

This should be at approx 50\%.

This should be at approx 75\%.

\page
\vspace*{\fill}

This page starts with an explicit \verb|\vspace*{\fill}|

You can see the first space is larger than the others.

This should be at 75\%.

\vspace{\fill}
\end{document}
```

Note, there are a few similar un-answered questions:

[Adding space before and after paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303349/adding-space-before-and-after-paragraph)
[How to add space before and after paragraph?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209002/how-to-add-space-before-and-after-paragraph)

Comment: You could also put each paragraph into a separate `\begin{figure}[p] ... \end{figure}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found close behavior when using `\vspace*{1\fill}` but couldn't explain why.  Thanks to David Carlisle's comment to my other (deleted) answer, I think I understand what's going on.

`\vspace*{1\fill}` adds zero-space, then starts a new paragraph (adding a new-line and then the implicit `\parskip` (aka `\fill`).  So the answer is to use the `\vspace*{}` to undo the newline, then let the implicit `\parskip` take care of the rest.

```
\newcommand{\nextpage}{\vspace{\fill}\newpage\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}
```

Here's the corrected MWE and the result.  It's not perfect.  Using my calipers on my physical screen, a better value is `\vspace*{-1.2\baselineskip}`.  I don't understand why, but that is good enough.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=88mm, paperwidth=62mm, margin=4mm, nomarginpar, showframe]{geometry}

\setlength{\parskip}{\fill}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newcommand{\nextpage}{\vfill\newpage\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}
\nextpage

This should be at approximately 50\%.

\nextpage

This should be at approx 33\%.

This should be at approx 66\%.

\nextpage

This should be at approx 25\%.

This should be at approx 50\%.

This should be at approx 75\%.

\nextpage

This page starts with an explicit \verb|\vspace*{\fill}|

You can see the first space is larger than the others.

This should be at 75\%.

\vspace{\fill}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It looks to me like the first paragraph is a little low

Comment: it would have been better to edit the previous example (or now delete in favour of this)

Comment: It's not clear what this post is about. The last page *doesn't* start with an explicit `\vspace{\fill}`, but *ends* with it.